# Win RT Deserialize XML to Object

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, windows-runtime, xml-deserialization

I've got a class to hold some details for an adviser:

```
namespace MortgageApp_2
{
[KnownType(typeof(MortgageApp_2.AdviserDetails))]
[DataContractAttribute]
public class AdviserDetails
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string Consultant { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string AddressOne { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string AddressTwo { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

}
}
```

The following code sterilizes the AdviserDetails to XML:

```
            StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string fileName = "AdviserDetails.xml";
        CreationCollisionOption options = CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;

        try
        {
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, options);

            using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(AdviserDetails));
                ser.WriteObject(stream, adDetails);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debugger.Break();

            throw;
        }
```

The created XMl file looks like this:

```
<AdviserDetails xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MortgageApp_2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><AddressOne>242 Office Block</AddressOne><AddressTwo>32 Hill Street</AddressTwo><City>Birmingham</City><Company>Best Mortgages</Company><Consultant>Bill Jones</Consultant><County>West Midlands</County><Postcode>B1 1AB</Postcode><Telephone>05100021300</Telephone></AdviserDetails>
```

The following code is then used to deserialize the XML to an object of type AdviserDetails:

```
  StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string fileName = "AdviserDetails.xml";
        string location = folder.Path + "\\" + fileName;
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(location).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AdviserDetails));
        var loadAdviser = (AdviserDetails)serializer.Deserialize(stream.AsInputStream().AsStreamForRead());
```

However, the last line:

```
var loadAdviser = (AdviserDetails)serializer.Deserialize(stream.AsInputStream().AsStreamForRead());
```

Throws an exception:

> There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

Does anyone know what is wrong, and how I could get my app to create an XMl file it can read?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**Serializer:**

```
    static async private Task SaveAsync<T>()
    {
        StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccess = await sessionFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        IOutputStream sessionOutputStream = sessionRandomAccess.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
        var sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<object>), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
        sessionSerializer.WriteObject(sessionOutputStream.AsStreamForWrite(), _data);
        await sessionOutputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
```

**Deserializer:**

```
   static async private Task RestoreAsync<T>()
    {
        StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        if (sessionFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        IInputStream sessionInputStream = await sessionFile.OpenReadAsync();
        var sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<object>), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
        _data = (List<object>)sessionSerializer.ReadObject(sessionInputStream.AsStreamForRead());
    }
```

Working Example: [Here](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/09/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/)

Comment: Got it working in the end, thank you very much for the link. :) Implementing XML stuff in Win RT is a real mission!!